# Cannot find bin directory for Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, path, pip, environment-variables, jupyter-lab

I have installed Jupyter Lab using pip:

```
pip install jupyterlab
```

As the documentation states, to be able to use the `jupyter lab` command on the command line, I first have to add the bin directories to my PATH environment variable. This wouldn't be a problem if I could actually find the bin directory. Other posts say that it should be easy to find by simply looking at the installation details on the terminal. I have read through them all, (and even searched for 'bin' within the terminal - no results), and do not seem to have any luck.

How do I find this directory? Thanks.

Comment: it should run also with `python -m jupyter lab`

Comment: @furas Bless you. I'm still slightly curious as to why I can't seem to find the bin folder, but if this works, I guess thats fine. Thanks.

Comment: `bin` can also means folder with executable programs but often it can have name `bin` or  `some_program_folder/bin/` - at least on Linux. Frankly, on Linux I didn't have to add any folder to `PATH` because it created program `jupyter` in some popular folder which already is in `PATH`

Comment: I found this program and it is Python's script with `from jupyter_core.command import main` and `main()` (and few other lines which propably are not so important)