# How can I locate the JupyterLab bin folder to add to PATH?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

I installed JupyterLab using

```
pip install jupyterlab
```

in my user directory. The installation guide says, "You must add the user-level bin directory to your PATH environment variable in order to launch jupyter lab" (and as expected, when I try to launch it with `jupyter lab`, it says the term is not recognized and doesn't launch anything). However, I cannot seem to locate said bin directory. Is there an easy way to track down its location? I'm using Windows 10.

I found the [same question from 3 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59113298/cannot-find-bin-directory-for-jupyter-lab) but it wasn't answered directly, only given an alternative solution for launching Jupyter - however, that alternative solution did not work for me, hence the re-posting of the question.

Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: On what OS? It matters.

Comment: @KenWhite Windows 10

Comment: Did you try searching in Windows Explorer for `*Jupyter*`?

Comment: @KenWhite I did yes (sorry, I should have mentioned that in my original post - first time posting here so I appreciate your patience :)). I've found where the Jupyter files and folders are in File Explorer, but when I go to the uppermost folder and search 'bin', no bin folder shows up.